# graphicsmagick outputs PDF instead of JPG?

Tags: graphicsmagick

Create thumbnail (JPG) of PDF file

```
gm convert -density 50 input.pdf[0] -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg
```

Can someone tell my why this command output a PDF as thumb.jpg? The contents of thumb.jpg is a PDF but should be JPG

```
gm -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.42 2023-09-23 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2023 GraphicsMagick Group.
```

I use the exact same command on another computer with same version of graphicsmagick and the output is JPG in the thumb.jpg file ?!

## update

```
gm convert -verbose -density 50 input.pdf[0] -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg
gm convert: "/usr/local/bin/gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r50x50" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gmBCanus" "--" "/tmp/gmsygPXL" "-c" "quit".
input.pdf PDF 413x585+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 707.9Ki 0.000u 0m:0.000776s (296.8Mi pixels/s)
input.pdf PDF 413x585=>99x140+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 0.010u 0m:0.002107s (109.3Mi pixels/s)
input.pdf=>thumb.jpg JPG 413x585=>99x140+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 0.000u 0m:0.000652s (353.5Mi pixels/s)
```

The output of `thumb.jpg`

```
%PDF-1.2 
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (thumb)
/CreationDate (D:20240116190220)
/ModDate (D:20240116190220)
/Producer (GraphicsMagick 1.3.42 2023-09-23 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one difference in your 1.3.42 Unix command and my 1.3.42 Windows one, and that is:-
I declare the files at the end `infile.pdf` then `out.jpg` .

`gm convert -verbose -density 50 -background white -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 "..\..\Sample (1).pdf" out.jpg`

[image]

JPEG, quality: 40, subsampling ON (2x2) image 108 x 140  Pixels (0.77)

You can bypass GraphicsMagick and faster simply use GS direct, either,

```
>%gs% "-q" "-sDEVICE=jpeg" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r50 -dDownScaleFactor=3"-oout2.jpg" -dJPEGQ=40  "..\..\Sample (1).pdf"
```

OR currently replace `-dJPEGQ=40` with `-dQFactor=1.25` both have the same effect.

```
>%gs% "-q" "-sDEVICE=jpeg" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r50 -dDownScaleFactor=3"-oout2.jpg" -dQFactor=1.25  "..\..\Sample (1).pdf
```

JPEG, quality: 40, subsampling ON (2x2), but file size was bigger  as 141 x 183  Pixels (0.77) because I only downscaled by 3, If I downscale by 4 it is closer as 106 x 137  Pixels (0.77)

[image]